How serialize and deserialize debezium message with quarkus stream
I'm having an issue with serializing and deserializing using debezium stream and quarkus streams. Here is my code:
1 - I wrote my pojo
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@RegisterForReflection
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonRootName("payload")
public class Payload {
    public After after;
    public Before before;
    public Source source;
    @JsonProperty("op")
    public String op;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Payload{" +
                "after=" + after +
                ", before=" + before +
                ", source=" + source +
                ", op=" + op +
                '}';
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@RegisterForReflection
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonRootName("after")
public class After {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public int id;
    @JsonProperty("redact_id")
    public int redact_id;
    @JsonProperty("descricao")
    public String descricao;
    @JsonProperty("data_inicial")
    public String data_inicial;
    @JsonProperty("data_final")
    public String data_final;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AfterFeriado{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", redact_id=" + redact_id +
                ", descricao=" + descricao +
                ", data_inicial=" + data_inicial +
                ", data_final=" + data_final +
                '}';
    }
}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@RegisterForReflection
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonRootName("before")
public class Before {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String id;
    @JsonProperty("redact_id")
    public String redact_id;
    @JsonProperty("descricao")
    public String descricao;
    @JsonProperty("data_inicial")
    public String data_inicial;
    @JsonProperty("data_final")
    public String data_final;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Before{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", redact_id=" + redact_id +
                ", descricao=" + descricao +
                ", data_inicial=" + data_inicial +
                ", data_final=" + data_final +
                '}';
    }
}


I don't know if I need put @JsonProperty("id") in pojo class.
The application properties
quarkus.kafka-streams.bootstrap-servers=kafkabrokershere:9092
// others props

quarkus.kafka-streams.topics=collector_topic


and finaly my function to return KStream,

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Topology {

    private final String COLLECTOR = "collector_topic";
    private final String UPDATE_TOPIC = "quarkus-udpated";
    private final String REMOVED_TOPIC = "quarkus-removed";

    @Produces
    public org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology buildTopology() {
        StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
        ObjectMapperSerde<PayloadToProducer> payloadToProducer = new ObjectMapperSerde<>(PayloadToProducer.class);

        var streamBuilder = this.buildStream(streamsBuilder);

        System.out.println(streamBuilder.peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("hereee"+k)));
        System.out.println(streamBuilder.peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("hereee"+v.op))); // null

        if (streamBuilder == null) {
            return null;
        }
        var operacaoDeCriacao = streamBuilder.filter((k,v) -> {
            var created = Objects.equals(v.op, "c") || Objects.equals(v.op, "u");
            System.out.println("null value here"+v);
            return created;
        });
        var operacaoDeRemocao = streamBuilder.filter((k,v) -> Objects.equals(v.op, "d"));
        this.mapperStream(operacaoDeCriacao).to(UPDATE_TOPIC, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), payloadToProducer));
        this.mapperStream(operacaoDeRemocao).to(REMOVED_TOPIC, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), payloadToProducer));

        return streamsBuilder.build();
    }

    private KStream<String, PayloadToProducer> mapperStream(KStream<String, Payload> stream) {
        return stream
                .map((k, v) -> {
                    // others operations to construct the new aggregated topic
                    var payloadToProducer = new PayloadToProducer(
                            2,2, 123, 123, "any valid information", LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now()
                    );
                    return new KeyValue<>(k, payloadToProducer);
                });
    }

    private KStream<String, Payload> buildStream(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
        // I try that
        ObjectMapperSerde<Payload> serdePayloadCurrent = new ObjectMapperSerde<>(Payload.class);

        // and I try that
        //Serde<Payload> serdePayloadCurrent = Serdes.serdeFrom(new PayloadSerializer(), new PayloadDeserializer());

        // And That
        //JsonSerde<Payload> payloadSerde = new JsonSerde<>(Payload.class);

        return streamsBuilder
                .stream(COLLECTOR, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), serdePayloadCurrent))
                .filter((k, v) -> {
                    System.out.println("value here null"+v.op);
                    return v != null;
                });
    }
}


serializer and deserializer, I think here is the problemn

public class PayloadDeserializer extends ObjectMapperDeserializer<Payload> {
        public PayloadDeserializer() {
            super(Payload.class);
    }
}

public class PayloadSerializer extends ObjectMapperSerializer<Payload> {
}


The deserializer and serializer are to
Serde serdePayloadCurrent = Serdes.serdeFrom(new PayloadSerializer(), new PayloadDeserializer()); and I put here because I try before.
Then return null in my stream, probrably is a deserializer probleman

What's the difference between Payload and DoClass? What is ObjectMapperDeserializer?

sorry, my bad... I forgot edit that

The ObjectMapperDeserializer is the class to implements the Deserializer, quarkus use that to deserializer one pojo

Can you show its implementation? It is possible the deserializer returns null. But Debezium itself shouldn't have a null value record
